# How to install cmake on Astra Linux 4.7?

Tags: linux, cmake

How to install cmake (also pbuilder, cowbuilder) on Astra Linux ? Details here:

```
user@baikal:~$ apt policy cmake
N: Unable to locate package cmake
user@baikal:~$ sudo astra-ce status
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
CE репозиторий не подключен
user@baikal:~$ sudo apt install cmake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cmake
user@baikal:~$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Astra Linux"
NAME="Astra Linux"
ID=astra
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="https://astralinux.ru"
SUPPORT_URL="https://astralinux.ru/support"
LOGO=astra
VERSION_ID=4.7_arm
VERSION_CODENAME=4.7_arm
user@baikal:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-110-generic
```

Comment: Also, it's interesting to have to use Astra Linux and have a location in New York, US, but I'll say that administrating stuff on the other end of the globe is a pretty normal thing.

Comment: looks like CMake isn't shipped by Astra Linux. Watching the video on the website of Astra Linux, it's "the only operating system that achieves the requirements of regulation for the ministry of defense and the FSB": Um thank you, that's about as much as I need to know: You're paying for a supported product, please ask your vendor. (you're using the kernel edition of the Astra Linux Special Edition, not the Common edition)